# Audio programming on Symbian devices

Tags: audio, symbian

I’m a blind programmer who would like to develop games based entirely on audio for symbian based phones. I need the ability to do the following. Get input from the phones joystick as well as regular keys, and play audio with varying volume and direction like can be done in directX. I know the  first part isn’t a problem in any language but am not sure about the second part. I know Java fairly well, Python to some extent and know c++ but am rusty. I’d like to use either Java or Python but am not sure if they offer the audio capabilities. Any links to libraries or sample code that could help me out would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaME on Symbian phones.

The relevant specifications for what you need are:

http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=118

and

http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=135

I would advise making a simple MIDlet that displays a Canvas.

You can then react to any key event by playing a different MIDI tone, for starters.

You should just avoid playing audio in the GUI callback thread.

The JavaME SDK will have example code for key event handling and audio playback.